# How to kill the app whenever the screen goes off?

Tags: android

I want to kill the app when ever the screen goes off, I mean if the screen timeout or when the lock button is pressed.

I've tried this method but it does not work for me, knowing that I call it at the beginning of the the `onCreate` method on my **MainActivity**:

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {

    final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();
    /** System Defined Broadcast */
    theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

    BroadcastReceiver screenOnOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String strAction = intent.getAction();

            KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            assert strAction != null;
            if(strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT) || strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)  ) {
                assert myKM != null;
                if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode())
                {
                    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);;
                } else
                {
                    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
                }
            }

        }
    };

    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(screenOnOffReceiver, theFilter);
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

1. Create a ScreenOnOffReceiver class & paste bellow code

   ```
   public class ScreenOnOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
     public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

      if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
       {
        //   Log.e("Sleep Time", getTimeForSleep(context)+"");

       }

      if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
      {
         // some code
         Log.e("screen-- ", "off");

         try {
           Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           context.startActivity(intent);
           ((Activity)context).finish();

         //  sleepTime = getTimeForSleep(context);

           } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
         }


       }

     }

    }
   ```
2. Add bellow code in MainActivity...

   ```
     ScreenOnOffReceiver sonoff;
       try {
          //Log.e("Error Welcome :","Welcome Begin");
          sonoff = new ScreenOnOffReceiver();
          IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
          intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
          intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
           registerReceiver(sonoff, intentFilter);
          //Log.e("Screen On Off ", "Started" );
        } catch (Exception e) {
          //Log.e("Error Welcome :", e.toString());
      }
   ```
3. Add Bellow code in  AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
      <receiver android:name=".ScreenOnOffReceiver">
           <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
           </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
   ```
4. I think your problem will be solved. Advance Thanks...Enamul